# Cannot start MySQL server following upgrade

Tags: mysql

I've just upgraded MySQL from 5.1.59 to 5.6.20 (OSX 10.7) and now the MySQL server will not start.

In MySQL Workbench (v6.1.7), in the startup/shutdown view, upon trying to start the server, the Startup Message Log reads as follows:

```
Could not open error log file: [Errno 2] The indicated path does not exist
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Starting server...
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Executing '/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start'
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Start server: Starting MySQL

2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Start server: .. ERROR! The server quit without updati
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Start server: ng PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/new-host-3.home.pid).

2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Server start done.
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Checking server status...
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (2002)
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Assuming server is not running
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Checking server status...
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (2002)
2014-09-06 11:21:52 - Assuming server is not running
```

And in /usr/local/mysql-5.6.20-osx10.7-x86_64/data/new-host-3.home.err reads as follows:

```
140906 11:30:57 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2014-09-06 11:30:57 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.20 started; log sequence number 1600927
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Binlog end
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-09-06 11:30:57 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1600937
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-09-06 11:30:59 2575 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

140906 11:30:59 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/new-host-3.home.pid ended
```

Btw there is a mysql.sock file in /var/mysql, and there is no mysqld process running.

I have not been able to run mysql_upgrade or anything else I've seen suggested to other users with similar symptoms, as I cannot start the server. This is beyond my MySQL consciousness; can someone please explain what has happened and how I can go about repairing this mess?

Any help will be very much appreciated,

svs

Answer (score 0):

This question is better asked on **dba.stackexchange.com**.

You have an unsupported option specified, either in the `my.cnf` file, or in the startup script.

```
[ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Likely, this option was valid with your previous version of MySQL, and was deprecated in a later release (which would likely have produced a `[WARNING]` during startup, and then subsequently made invalid in the release you are now running.

The "fix" would be to locate that option in the my.cnf file, and remove it. (There's a sequence of directories where mysqld looks for the `my.cnf` file, depending on release and OS ( `/etc/my.cnf`, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, mysql installation directory, etc.  Options can also be specified on the command line that starts mysqld; less likely, it's possible that option is  being supplied from mysqld_safe script.)

Comment: Thx, I've posted there.